# SQL Server 2005 - Pivoting Data without a sum / count and dynamic list of values

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, t-sql, pivot

Sorry if this is covered elsewhere in another question, but I can't find any examples which exactly match what I need and I'm getting confused.

I have data in the table like this :-

```
Name   |   Value
---------------
John   |   Dog
John   |   Cat
John   |   Fish
Bob    |   Python
Bob    |   Camel
```

And I would like the data like this....

```
Name   |  Value_1 | Value_2 | Value_3
-------------------------------------
John   |  Dog     |  Cat    | Fish
Bob    |  Python  |  Camel  | NULL
```

I don't want to use case statements because the dog, cat, fish etc there are 20+ possible values and they could change overtime.

Anyone got any pointers?

Answer (score 3):

This comes close to what you're after.  i've also included a table creation script and sample data for others to use.  Inspiration for this solution came from [here](http://www.eggheadcafe.com/conversation.aspx?messageid=34036571&threadid=34036565)

```
-- Dynamic PIVOT
DECLARE @T AS TABLE(y INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY);

DECLARE
@cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
@y    AS INT,
@sql  AS NVARCHAR(MAX);

-- Construct the column list for the IN clause
-- e.g., [Dog],[Python]
SET @cols = STUFF(
(SELECT N',' + QUOTENAME(y) AS [text()]
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT [Value] AS y FROM dbo.table_1) AS Y
ORDER BY y
FOR XML PATH('')),
1, 1, N'');

-- Construct the full T-SQL statement
-- and execute dynamically
SET @sql = N'SELECT *
FROM (SELECT *
FROM dbo.table_1) AS D
PIVOT(MIN(value) FOR value IN(' + @cols + N')) AS P;';

PRINT @sql
EXEC sp_executesql @sql;
GO
```

Table creation:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Table_1](
    [Name] [varchar](50) COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AS NULL,
    [Value] [varchar](50) COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AS NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO
```

Sample data:

```
insert into dbo.table_1 values ('John','Dog')
insert into dbo.table_1 values ('John','Cat')
insert into dbo.table_1 values ('John','Fish')
insert into dbo.table_1 values ('Bob ','Python')
insert into dbo.table_1 values ('Bob ','Camel')
```

Comment: Thanks, I think this will probably do the job for now :)

Answer (score 0):

This question is somewhat similar:

[Cross Tab - Storing different dates (Meeting1, Meeting2, Meeting 3 etc) in the same column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1434717/cross-tab-storing-different-dates-meeting1-meeting2-meeting-3-etc-in-the-sa/1435112#1435112)

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this :

http://dotnetgalactics.wordpress.com/2009/10/23/using-sql-server-20052008-pivot-on-unknown-number-of-columns-dynamic-pivot/

Might be helpful ..